# CakePHP join and conditions optimization harsh critique PLEASE

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Can I have a new set of eyes look at my query (which is working as intended), but I am looking for harsh critique and suggestions or ways of improvement:

...

```
$options = array(
    'joins'      => array(
        array(
            'table'      => 'plans_zips',
            'alias'      => 'PZips',
            'type'       => 'inner',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array('Plan.id = PZips.plan_id')
        ),
        array(
            'table'      => 'zips',
            'alias'      => 'Zips',
            'type'       => 'inner',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array('Zips.id = PZips.zip_id')
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        "OR" => array(
            'AND' => array(
                $ApplicantAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age',
                'Zips.title'               => $Zip,
                'Applicant.amount'         => array($comboType, $memberCount),
            "NOT" => 
                array(array('PlanDetail.company_id' => array('27','3')))),
            array(
                $PsSpouseAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age',
                'Zips.title'            => $Zip,
                'Applicant.amount'      => array($comboType, $memberCount),
                'PlanDetail.company_id' => '27'),
            array(
                $OdsSpouseAge . ' BETWEEN Age.Min_Age AND Age.Max_age',
                'Zips.title'            => $Zip,
                'Applicant.amount'      => array($comboType, $memberCount),
                'PlanDetail.company_id' => '3'))
),
    'contain'    => array(
        'PlanDetail' => array(
            'fields'   => array(
                'id',
                'effective_date',
                'expiration_date',
                'active',
                'name',
                'plan_type_id',
                'max_benefit',
                'deductible',
                'preventive',
                'basic',
                'major',
                'ortho',
                'application_url',
                'company_id',
                'plan_type_id',
                'plan_detail_note_id'),
            'Company'  => array('fields' => array(
                'id',
                'name',
                'company_logo_url'
            )),
            'PlanType' => array('fields' => array(
                'id',
                'name',
                'description'
            ))),
        'Age'        => array('fields' => array(
            'id',
            'name',
        )),
        'Applicant'  => array('fields' => array(
            'id',
            'name',
        )),
        'Zip'        => array('fields' => array(
            'id',
            'title')
        )
    ),
    'limit'      => 100,
    'order'      => array('monthly_cost' => 'ASC')
);
if ($Vision == 1) {
    array_push($options['conditions'], "dental_cost > 0");
}
```

...

Comment: If it's the same script and same database schema, it's probably the MySQL server. You may need to optimize your server. Try running the script found in this [article](http://www.joehayes.org/optimizing-mysql-for-dummies.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest working on simplifying the query, perhaps by executing multiple smaller queries. Otherwise the only other option will be to optimize your database engine or use the mysql profiler to try optimize the query in SQL for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post to a pastebin somewhere the query log generated when debug > 1?

Also - post the describe statement results from the mysql db so we can see your indexes / table structure.

Without looking at the generated query/queries and seeing the database info there is no realistic way anybody can evaluate this.

Comment: Abba, I posted a query result set and the table structures. Although I indexed the plans_zips table, I don't see it in the output of the structure. Here is the link: http://pastebin.com/9SRXFdqK

Comment: Wow, I see a ton of duplicated queries in there. Have a reason for querying the Age table so many times on the same id's?

Comment: I would start with caching the queries that get repeated over and over on the Age table (and others) or where you are doing the query maybe toss the first result set from any find( 'all' ) into a variable instead of re-querying the db. If it is all coming from relations then maybe you should look at implementing queryCache or one of the many cache plugins.